# Executing SSIS package programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssis, package

Below is the code I will be referring to. A few questions:

1. Am I able to reference two different .DTSX files within one "String pkgLocation =" statement? (I did it below), if I am unable to do so, and have over 10 different packages to execute programmatically, is there a quick and painless way to go about this?
2. Does the code below represent Entity Framework at all?
3. Its been a while since I played with SSIS and I am wondering how to specifically execute it? simply pressing "Run" shows me nothing within the Test Explorer (probably because its not a test) and when I attempt to Execute it I receive a message stating "project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly" What does that even mean?
4. Am I on the right track? (with regards to executing these packages programmatically)

---

```
public class UnitTest1
    {

        private void Execute_Package()
        {
            string pkgLocation = @"C:\tfs\z Reports\BI Projects\Customer Service Data Warehouse\Customer Service Data Warehouse" +
                                 @"C:\tfs\z Reports\BI Projects\Customer Service Data Warehouse\SRS DataMart SSIS\SRSDimCategorizationLoad.dtsx";
            Package pkg;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            Variables vars;

            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

            vars = pkg.Variables;
            vars["A_Variable"].Value = "Some value";

            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();


        }
    }
```

---

Here is the **old code** that I made into the code above:

```
private static void LoadTicketLifeCycleSnapShotFact()
        {
            ExceutePackage(@"C:\tfs\z Reports\BI Projects\Customer Service Data Warehouse\Customer Service Data Warehouse\SAPBPDataToStage.dtsx");

            ExceutePackage(@"C:\tfs\z Reports\BI Projects\Customer Service Data Warehouse\SRS DataMart  SSIS\SRSDimCategorizationLoad.dtsx");
```

Comment: Were your packages built using the Project Deployment model? This is new in 2012

Comment: I completely forget how to execute SSIS packages programmatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array of the package locations and then enumerate through them calling the Execute method for each of them.

```
    private void Execute_Package()
    {
        string [] pkgLocations = new string[]{
            @"C:\tfs\z Reports\BI Projects\Customer Service Data Warehouse\Customer Service Data Warehouse",
            @"C:\tfs\z Reports\BI Projects\Customer Service Data Warehouse\SRS DataMart SSIS\SRSDimCategorizationLoad.dtsx"};
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        Variables vars;

        app = new Application();
        foreach(string currentFile in pkgLocations)
        {
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(currentFile, null);

            // Assumes this variable exists in all of the packages
            vars = pkg.Variables;
            vars["A_Variable"].Value = "Some value";

            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
        }
    }
```

To answer the specific questions you raised:

1. No, you cannot reference them as you specified. The above is how you would execute the packages in sequence.
2. I have no clue whether this is "EF". I assume not
3. You've created a test `library`. A library isn't a runnable thing. Something else needs to make it go (something with a Main method). For testing, this will be your test harness (nUnit). Alternatively, I'd create a Console app that uses the testing project to ensure you've built your test cases correctly (and then you create a test project to test your test...)
4. Yes, your code above instantiates a package, assigns a value to an SSIS variable and then runs the package with that new variable.